# Android SWITCH . how do I change the on color to green

Tags: android, layout

Below is code to add a switch to a table layout. When the switch is touch it turns RED.  I need it to be GREEN.

I have tried everything to change the ON color to green with no success.

```
 Switch sw1 = new Switch(this);
 sw1.setTag(i);
 if (switchonoff.get(i).equals("true"))
        {
            sw1.setChecked(true);

        }
        else
        {
           sw1.setChecked(false);
         }
        sw1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
             {
                @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                    {
                        System.out.println("____Switch State: isChecked: " + isChecked +  " " + buttonView.getTag() );
                        Integer tmpint = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();
                        if (isChecked)
                        {
                            switchonoff.set(tmpint, "true");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            switchonoff.set(tmpint, "false");
                        }

                        for (int i=0; i<mnumberofrows; i++ )
                        {
                            System.out.println("________Switch State: isChecked " + i + " " + switchonoff.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 46):

The color of the switch is determined by the theme or style of your app. You will need to create a custom style and apply it to your switch. With

**Edit values\styles.xml with the following**

```
<style name="SwitchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#148E13</item>
</style>
```

Now we just need to apply it to the switch.

```
<Switch
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="New Switch"
  android:id="@+id/switch1"
  android:theme="@style/SwitchTheme" <--- Important line
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="78dp" />
```

Then we are left with the following:

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: Theme attribute doesn't work in RecyclerView on pre-material APIs.

Comment: Requires min api level 21. Recommended api level is 14

Comment: For minimum api level, use ' <item name="colorControlActivated">#148E13</item> ' insted of ' <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#148E13</item> '

Comment: This doesn't work for `androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat`

Answer (score 5):

This answer will help those that will be using **`SwitchMaterial`** rather than **`Switch`**

Here's an example of a `SwitchMaterial` in XML. Set a custom theme as seen in the last line of the xml

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
    android:id="@+id/switchLocks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/filter_lock_title"
    android:theme="@style/FilterSwitchThemeGreen" />
```

In your `values/styles.xml` add a style for your switch.

```
<style name="FilterSwitchThemeGreen" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

Before: [image: red switch]

After: [image: green switch]

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do, change the background color:

setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);

As:

```
holper.aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked){

                    buttonView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
                }
```

}